# mysql sub select newbie

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

```
SELECT a.lead_id, c.state_name AS COL1DATA, count( c.state_name ) AS leadcount, (

SELECT count( won_loss ) AS wonlosscount
FROM lead_status
WHERE (won_loss = 'loss')
AND lead_id = a.lead_id
) AS losscount
FROM lead AS a
JOIN states AS c ON a.state_id = c.states_id
GROUP BY c.state_name
ORDER BY losscount DESC
```

the answer i get is

```
lead_id     COL1DATA    leadcount   losscount
1           Queensland  7            0
8           Victoria    3            0
```

lead status

```
lead_id     won_loss    won_price   won_mainreason  loss_mainreason     loss_attachment_id  lost_dont_sell_note     add_note    dealer_satisfaction
      5     win         4655        pricing                                                                         fghfg       somewhat
      8     won         34543       pricing                                                                         sfdgs       satisfied
      7     loss                                    service                                                         Additional Notes    verygood
      9     loss                                    not_in_stock                                                    Additi      satisfied
```

but the loss count should be 1 and 1

any help is appricated

Comment: Can you post the contents of `lead_status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's a problem with mixing the non-aggregated lead_id in the correlated query all the while grouping on state_name. Perhaps you can describe what you're looking to get back.

**EDIT:** Based on OP feedback in comment below.

**EDIT 2:** Changed to left outer joins based on chat session. Not all leads have a lead_status.

```
SELECT
    s.state_name AS COL1DATA, count(c.state_name) AS leadcount,
    sum(case when ls.won_loss = 'loss' then 1 else 0 end) as losscount
FROM
    lead AS l
    INNER JOIN states AS s ON s.state_id = l.states_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_status as ls on ls.lead_id = l.lead_id
GROUP BY s.state_name
ORDER BY losscount DESC
```

I might argue that this version is slightly better. But I didn't want to totally change your query. (I did change the aliases because A and C were confusing.)

```
SELECT
    min(s.state_name) AS COL1DATA,
    count(l.lead_id) AS leadcount, /* counting non-nullable key on the outer side */
    sum(case when ls.won_loss = 'loss' then 1 else 0 end) as losscount
FROM
    lead AS l
    INNER JOIN states AS s ON s.state_id = l.states_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_status as ls on ls.lead_id = l.lead_id
GROUP BY s.state_id /* might be better to group on the id */
ORDER BY losscount DESC
```

The lead_id column you have included in the output is unpredictable unless the group only has one row. Based on what you've said, I doubt that you really want it.

Comment: no problem on that.,.. what i looking ot get back is the total number of leads per state and the number of lost leads per state see the ansewr given by John woo ...he seems to be getting there but not quite there yet...

Comment: shawn: the total lead count is showing as totl number won_loss .... for eg i can have 10 leads out of whihc only 2 are won or 3 loss  so lead count should 10 loss count should be 3

Comment: Obviously we can't guess at the final numbers without seeing some data. The `count(l.lead_id)` expression is going to count the number of rows per group without any regard for the won_loss value.

Comment: shawn its right now its not doing that ...if i have total number of loss =2 (say state 1 loss = 1 and state2 loss = 1 ) total leads  is showing up as (leadcount) = 2

Comment: @NMFSDF I'm not sure I followed that, but it sounds like there's either not enough data for the full picture or you're possibly misinterpreting the numbers. The description you gave a few comments back is pretty straightforward. Is it possible that you left out a small detail? I could give you an answer very quickly if you posted all the table data.

Comment: i am tryign ot figure out a way to invite you to a chat where i can post the tables ...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15108/discussion-between-nmf-sdf-and-john-totet-woo  --- can you join this ?